# using between in the middle of where clause based on an if condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
Select * from MyTable 
    where myField = 1
    And myImportantField ???
    ...
```

i have following parameters :

```
@DoCalculateValues bit,  
@FromValue int,  
@ToValue int
```

I NEED THIS

```
if @DoCalculateValues = 1 then  
check if myImportantField is between @FromValue and @ToValue  
else  
ignore values, something like "And myImportantValue = myImportantValue"
```

please consider that this is all happening in the middle of a "... WHERE ... AND ..." clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Select * from MyTable 
where myField = 1
And (@DoCalculateValues = 0
or myImportantField between @FromValue and @ToValue)
```

Comment: You need to use braces to differentiate the order and need to take care of negative values for @DoCalculateValues

Comment: `@DoCalculateValues` is a `bit` and can only be `0` or `1`

Comment: Wrong, it gives you And (true) or And (False) neither is my answer

Comment: @mahditahsildari: Why do you think this is wrong? If `@DoCalculateValues` is 0, the part in the brackets will evaluate to `true` regardless of `myImportantField` values. And if it is 1, then the result will depend on whether `myImportantField` is indeed between `@FromValue` and `@ToValue`, just like you seem to want.

Comment: yes you are RIGHT, sorry there was a little problem in my code, i removed it and it worked. Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from MyTable  
where myField = 1 
And ((myImportantField between @FromValue and @ToValue and @DoCalculateValues = 1)
OR  ( @DoCalculateValues <> 1))
```